# Hide 3D cursor's axes

Tags: 3d-view, interface, 3d-cursor

I accidentally turned on my 3D cursor's "axes" on the viewport. Now it looks like this:

[image]

It's really annoying and I have no idea how I turned this on. How to get rid of it (but still shows the 3D cursor itself?)

Comment: Oh, you again! Man, IDK if a bird got into your 3D cursor setting or what, but God, help you.

Comment: Try to reset to default